# Property of a connected graph with even no. of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, combinations

Let $G$ be a connected graph with an even number of vertices. Prove that you can select a subset of edges of $G$ such that each vertex is incident to an odd number of selected edges.

I am thinking induction is a possible way out but I have no idea if it really works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each subset $A\subseteq E$, let $f(A)\subseteq V$ be the set of vertices of $G$ that are incident with an odd number of edges in $A$.  Note that $|f(A)|$ is always even (per hand-shaking). As $|V|$ is even, $|V\setminus f(A)|$ is also even.
Pick a set $A$ that maximizes $|f(A)|$. If $f(A)\ne V$, there exist at least two vertices $v,w\in V\setminus f(A)$. As $G$ is connected, there is a path from $v$ to $w$. Let $A'$ be the symmetric difference of $A$ and the edges in this path. Then $f(A')=f(A)\cup \{v,w\}$, contradicting maximality. We conclude $f(A)=V$.

---

A variation to the above theme:
Group the vertices of $G$ into disjoint pairs.
For each such pair $(v,w)$, pick a path from $v$ to $w$.
Let $A$ be the set of edges that are used in an odd number of these paths. Verify that this does the trick.

Comment: What does "disjoint pairs" mean ? What is the guarantee that the entire graph can be partitioned accordingly ? Sorry if I am missing something obvious .

Answer (score 4):

Since the sum of degrees of vertices in $G$ must be even, then $G$ has even number of vertices with odd degree. Also, since number of vertices in $G$ is even, there is an even number of vertices with even degree.

Consider a shortest path whose endpoints are vertices with even degree. Clearly, this path exists because $G$ is connected. Let this path be $P=v_1 v_2 \ldots v_l$. $v_1$ and $v_l$ have even degree, and rest of the vertices in this path have odd degree, because if some $v_x \in P$ for $2 \le x \le l-1$ has even degree, path $v_1 v_2\ldots v_x$ would have shorter length than path $P$, and it’s endpoints would have even degree, but this is a contradiction since $P$ is shortest path with this property.

Now, we apply following algorithm so that vertices $v_1$ and $v_l$ become vertices with odd degree, and rest of them stay with odd degree. First, we remove edge $v_1 v_2$. $v_1$ now has odd degree, $v_2$ has even degree. Then, we remove edge $v_2 v_3$. $v_2$ now has odd degree, but $v_3$ has even degree.

We continue this algorithm; more precisely, we remove edges $v_i v_{i+1}$ for $1 \le i \le l-2$ in this order, and we get in situation where only $v_{l-1}$ and $v_l$ have even degree in path $P$. Finally, remove edge $v_{l-1} v_l$ and they both become vertices with odd degree.

Now, all vertices in path P have odd degree. We decreased total number of vertices with even degree by two. We repeat this algorithm (find a shortest path whose endpoints are vertices of even degree and then apply described algorithm to change parity of endpoints ) until number of vertices with even degree becomes $0$, and it will, because we said that totally there is even number of these vertices, and in every step, we change parity of two of them. This completes the proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your post would be a lot easier to read if you used Mathjax/Latex to format the maths, and introduced some line and/or paragraph breaks.

Comment: But the algorithm of removing edges might result in the resulting subgraph being disconnected? For example, consider the path $v_1 - v_2 - v_3$, where $v_1$ and $v_3$ are of even degree while $v_2$ is of odd degree 3. Then removing the edges $v_1v_2$ and $v_2v_3$ causes $v_2$ to have degree 1, hence the subgraph might be disconnected. If this happens, the shortest path might not exist, right? How do we resolve this issue, or am I missing something?